# get message id or timestamp in StanzaIdAcknowledgedListener in ejabberd

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

I enabled mam archiving in ejabberd , when I send a messsage to users ,
the receiver of message has information about timestamp of message in received packet like bellow

```
<archived by='989138553343@192.168.43.67' id='1508653008093085' 
xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp'/>
```

is it pussible to get this info in StanzaIdAcknowledgedListener that I am using it like bellow :
(I am using ejabbeejabberd-17.08 server and smack in android client .)

```
mConnection.addStanzaIdAcknowledgedListener(stanzaId, new 
 StanzaListener() {
  @Override
    public void processStanza(final Stanza packet) throws 
    SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException {
    AndroidUtilities.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
      //handle ack received by server
      }
   });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using `DelayInformation` message extension if you have got it in message stanza.use below namespace and elementname for get id and timestamp.

```
  Message msg = (Message) stanza; //your stanza packet

  if(msg.getExtension(DeliveryReceipt.ELEMENT,DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE) !=null){

         DelayInformation timestamp = (DelayInformation)msg.getExtension("delay", "urn:xmpp:delay");
                if (timestamp == null)
                    timestamp = (DelayInformation)msg.getExtension("x", "jabber:x:delay");
                if (timestamp != null)
                    ts = timestamp.getStamp().getTime();
                else
                    ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
     }
```